# Qt and SSMS Express

Tags: sql, qt, express

I have developed an application in qt and connected a database to it by SSMS Express.  How can I deploy this program so that this data is available to the program when installed on another computer?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Put your database file , near your project then deploy it . I can't understand what was different , that you say ssms express. It's important that you use SQL db. You have db file.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R do you know how can i get .db file from SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You should [Export your DB](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9248/import-and-export-data-with-sql-server-management-studio/)
then you should put db file near Exe File that you want to deploy.

watch this youtube video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCXAgB6y8eA